# Updating global property in oozie sub workflow

Tags: workflow, oozie, oozie-coordinator

Is it possible to override global property value in the sub-workflows?

In main/workflow.xml

```
    <workflow-app name="test-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">

         <global>
              <configuration>
                 <property>
                    <name>global-prop</name>
                    <value>global-val</value>
                 </property>
              </configuration>
         <global>

    <start to="start" />
       <action name="start">
          <sub-workflow>
             <app-path>${wf:appPath()}/start</app-path>
             ....
             ...
    <decision name="wf-decision">
       <switch>
           <case to="wf-A">${global-prop}</case> 
<!-- can the value of global-prop be updated in main/start/workflow.xml, ie start subworkflow -->
           <default to="end" />
        </switch>
    </decision>
```

When the workflow comes to decision node, it takes path depending on global-prob. I want the global-prop value to depend on the outcome of start sub-workflow.

Answer (score 1):

> *decision node ... depending on global-prop. I want the global-prop
>   value to depend on the outcome of sub-workflow*

**¤** Comment #1: from general principles, it would make more sense to have the decision depend on *both* the outcome and the global (and constant) property. Using a boolean EL expression for instance *(cf. some examples [there](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaim.html))*.

**¤** Comment #2: there is a lot of confusion in the [Oozie documentation](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.1_Workflow_Job_Properties_or_Parameters) between ***properties*** as a short for *Hadoop properties*, that are transmitted to the YARN jobs; and *Workflow properties* also called ***parameters*** that are EL variables (called *properties* again in the EL documentation, damn)  that are used to define values for properties/arguments/etc. but not transmitted to the YARN jobs.

The way you are using your "global-prop", it should be defined in the `<parameters>` section instead of `<global>`.

**¤** Comment #3: AFAIK Oozie parameters and properties are immutable; you can set their value just once, using...

- parameters> hard-coded string literals
- properties> literals and/or parameters and/or EL functions

There is also a matter of scope -- i.e. when a "global" property and a "local" property *(defined inside an Action of Sub-Workflow, again from string/param/EL fct)* have the same exact name, the "local" one takes precedence.

**¤** Comment #4: there is a way to retrieve some custom status information from a Java / Pig / Shell action, using the `<capture-output>` procedure *(see the classical [example](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2.6_Hadoop_Jobs_EL_Function) in Oozie documentation)* but you can only retrieve it from the *same* Workflow. With a Sub-Workflow, executed in a separate context with a distinct ID, you are out of luck.

**¤** Soooo... when everything else has failed, the only hope is to go **back to basics**. Ever heard of that empty HDFS file named `_SUCCESS` that Pig creates on completion, so that further processing can be triggered automatically (by an oozie Coordinator for instance)?

If the Sub-Workflow somehow creates a HDFS file with a pre-defined name, then the Decision could use an [HDFS EL function](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2.7_HDFS_EL_Functions) to check whether that file has been created or not:

```
 <case to="Happy">${fs:exists(concat(wf:conf("status.dir"),"/__HAPPY"))}</case>
```